# Rails: boolean attr_accessible default method behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, boolean, attr-accessible

I have a normal class (Event) where a boolean value is defined as

```
 attr_accessible :archived
```

and in the db schema is

```
t.boolean  "archived",                          :default => false
```

As such, the default method archived? is automatically defined.

After a debugging session I discovered this

```
>> a=Event.last
>> a.archived
false
>> a.archived=true
true
>> a.archived
true
>> a.archived?
false
```

Should't the last two values BOTH be true? What am I missing here?

Even this is not helping:

```
>> a.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (45.2ms)  UPDATE "events" SET "archived" = 't', "updated_at" = '2012-12-10 06:31:57.410990' WHERE "events"."id" = 3
true
   (149.5ms)  commit transaction
>> a.archived?
false
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is your database engine ?

Comment: What does attr_accessible have to do with the issue you're seeing?

Comment: I wonder if it makes a difference that you haven't saved `a` yet. Before calling `a.archived?` what if you call `a.save` first?

Comment: I don't see the behavior you're claiming. What else is going on?

Comment: In agreement with @muistooshort; I'm seeing the same thing. What version of Ruby and Rails are you using?

Comment: the last code, I think it return false because you didn't save the object, so `a.archived?` still return false, if you run `a.save` then `a.archived?`, I think it will return `true`.

Comment: To all: it' sqllite and Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.3
To Beelrington: I don't knoe, I just tried to give all possible info
I'll try to save when I'm back home